# Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue DataPower SharePoint angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, cors, ibm-datapower

We are working in a SharePoint application. The app is developed using AngularJS and deployed into our company SAAS sharepoint site. The AngularJS application is consumes web services hosted in application server. The Angular JS application invokes the DataPower url (reverse proxy) to get the data from application server (no communication from Angular JS app to Application Server). When we invoke the URL https://company-qa.mycompany.com/path/services/resource we are getting following error,

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://company-qa.mycompany.com/path/services/resource. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://mycompany.sharepoint.com' is therefore not
>   allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

The company-qa.mycompany.com is Data Power URL. We are given following Header Injection parameters in the Data Power

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://mycompany.sharepoint.com
```

In the application server also, we have given above headers. Any clue, anything needs to be done in Sharepoint? Or any special header needs to be passed from AngularJS app?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: *The response had HTTP status code 401* is an error response that means you’re unauthorized. Many/most web servers don’t set the *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* header on error responses. So you first need to figure out how to access that *https://company-qa.mycompany.com/path/services/resource* resource without getting an error response

Answer (score 2):

enable options method in FSH, and add options to match action in a separate rule. then in MPGW advanced tab enable process messages whose body is empty. then on the first request rule for options call send the dp response headers with putting skip back-side. and send these headers Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://mycompany.sharepoint.com. dont forget to send the same headers in actual response as well.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Chrome, on Windows. To disable the `CORS` filter, so that you can only deal with the remaining exceptions, do the following:

Exit chrome(kill all instances). Press Windows Icon then letter R as you keep windows key down. Paste the command below on the resulting box and press enter.

> chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session"
>   --disable-web-security

This will open Chrome with **websecurity** disabled(no CORS filter). Make sure there's a warning message on chrome when it opens. Run your app and let me know what you get as an exception.

Also, make sure that your credentials are correct, since `HTTP status code 401`implies that you're running into an **Authentication issue**.